# Visual Studio HTML formatter: Hitting enter removes all indents in the previous line

Tags: html, formatter, visual-studio-2015

Running Visual Studio Community 2015 (but have seen the problem in earlier versions as well), and when I'm editing an HTML-file, when I hit enter to go to the next line, the line I just left is moved to the left, removing the indents. `Ctrl-K,D` reformats the line again. Pretty annoying?

Before enter:

[image: Before enter]

After enter:

[image]

Identing is set to Smart in `Text Editor|HTML|Tabs` as well as `Text Editor|HTML (Web Forms)|Tabs`

Seems like a bug, why would anyone need that behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

### Solution:

It just hit me: ReSharper? And yes, I tried suspending ReSharper in Options|ReSharper and the weird behaviour went away.

After some trial'n'error, I found the option: `ReSharper|Options` and `Code Editing|HTML|Formatting Style|Do not indent children of`.

Apparently ReSharper don't want children of the body tag to be indented. I don't agree. Removed "body" from the setting, and all is bliss now.

[image]

Comment: Was looking for this for over an hour. Thanks.